# state is not getting updated with usestate

Tags: reactjs, accordion, use-state

I am trying to get selected item from list . The list is in accordion. after selecting item the accordion should be closed. Selection item is working fine but unable to close the accordion.

here is my accordion with list.

```
mycomponent.js

    <Accordion isExpand={isExpand}>
            <List data-testid="steptwo-list" data={data} renderItem={renderListItem} />
          </Accordion>

this is my click action of list .



  const renderListItem = useCallback(({ value, selected }) => {
            return (
              <div onClick={() => addHandler(value)} className="lisr">
                <div className={selected ? "value" : "highlight"}>{value}</div>
              </div>
            );
          }, []);
```

this is how I am adding selected item to list and trying to close the accordion.

```
  let addHandler = (value) => {
            if (!checkedItems.includes(value)) {
              setCheckedItems((prevState) => [...prevState, value]);
            }
            setIsExpand(false);
          };
```

isExpand comes from prop

```
  Accordion.js

    const [expand, setExpand] = useState(isExpand);

accordion toggle action

    const toggle = useCallback(() => {
        if (!disabled) {
            setExpand((expand) => !expand);
        }
    }, [disabled, setExpand]);

checking isExpand 

useEffect(() => {
    useEffect(() => setExpand(isExpand), [isExpand]

}, [isExpand])
```

Comment: just wanted to ask: why `setExpand((expand) => !expand);` instead of `setExpand(!expand);`?

Comment: setExpand((expand) => !expand); this is in other component. you can see it one is mycomponent.js and   Accordion.js

Answer (score 1):

```
**I have created a sample code you can try like this:**

class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isExpanded: 0
        }
    }

    onChangeAccordian = (index) => {
        this.setState({
            isExpanded: index
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Accordion activeKey={this.state.isExpanded} onSelect={(e) => this.onChangeAccordian(e)}>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="1" >
                            Title1
                                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                        <Card.Body>
                            Body1
                                        </Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="2">
                            Title2
                                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="2">
                        <Card.Body>
                            Body2
                                        </Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
            </Accordion>

        );
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but my accordion is woking fine, this snipper won't help me

Comment: @RaheshSJ123 as you have mentioned in your question that "accordion should be closed but its not working", so I gave you solution for this issue. If issue is different than can you please explain.

Comment: Accordion is closing directly if I click on div and also it should be closed when I click on list item/ when addHandler triggered

Answer (score 0):

You're using functions to set your states, but you don't enclose them in curly brackets. Try that. Ex:

`setCheckedItems((prevState) => { [...prevState, value] })`

OR

```
useEffect(() => {
   setExpand((expand) => {!expand}) 
}, [isExpand])
```